# Determining an unknown percentage

Tags: statistics

A statistical report has shown that in 2012, 66% of elderly people didn't use internet. In 2015, it decreased to 50%. What percent of elderly people haven't been using the internet between 2012 and 2015?

I'm not sure I understand the question. It's obviously not 16%, but how can I determine the correct percentage?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that they are asking for the average, so.. 66% did not use the internet in 2012 and 50% did not use it in 2015. The average would then be: $$\frac{\frac{66}{100}+\frac{50}{100}}{2}=58\%$$
I might be completely off, but that's how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Just found the correct answer is 47%, but no solution. Don't know how they got it?

Comment: @Quant Are you sure you’ve included all the information? Seems like the question can’t be solved otherwise since we don’t know what the percentages were during 2013 and 2014.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I am so confused. This is all the info the problem has..